# R function loglik() returning -inf?

Tags: r, function, simulation, modeling

Simulating an SIR model in R. I have a data set I am trying to plot accurately with the model. I am right now using the particle filter function, then would like to use the corresponding logLik method on the result. When I do this, I get "[1] -Inf" as a result. I can't find in the documentation why this is and how I can avoid it. Are my parameters for the model not accurate enough? Is there something else wrong?

My function looks like this:
SIRsim %>%
pfilter(Np=5000) -> pf
logLik(pf)

From an online course lesson entitled Likelihood for POMPS https://kingaa.github.io/sbied/pfilter/ , this is the R script for the lesson. However, the code works here... I'm not sure how to reproduce my specific problem with it and unfortunately cannot share the dataset or code I am using because it is for academic research.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pomp)
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
stopifnot(packageVersion("pomp")>="3.0")
set.seed(1350254336)

library(tidyverse)
library(pomp)

sir_step <- Csnippet("
double dN_SI = rbinom(S,1-exp(-Beta*I/N*dt));
double dN_IR = rbinom(I,1-exp(-mu_IR*dt));
S -= dN_SI;
I += dN_SI - dN_IR;
R += dN_IR;
H += dN_IR;
")

sir_init <- Csnippet("
S = nearbyint(eta*N);
I = 1;
R = nearbyint((1-eta)*N);
H = 0;
")

dmeas <- Csnippet("
lik = dbinom(reports,H,rho,give_log);
")

rmeas <- Csnippet("
reports = rbinom(H,rho);
")

read_csv("https://kingaa.github.io/sbied/pfilter/Measles_Consett_1948.csv") 
%>%
  select(week,reports=cases) %>%
  filter(week<=42) %>%
  pomp(
    times="week",t0=0,
    rprocess=euler(sir_step,delta.t=1/7),
    rinit=sir_init,
    rmeasure=rmeas,
    dmeasure=dmeas,
    accumvars="H",
    statenames=c("S","I","R","H"),
    paramnames=c("Beta","mu_IR","eta","rho","N"),
    params=c(Beta=15,mu_IR=0.5,rho=0.5,eta=0.06,N=38000)
  ) -> measSIR

measSIR %>%
  pfilter(Np=5000) -> pf
logLik(pf)

library(doParallel)
library(doRNG)
registerDoParallel()
registerDoRNG(652643293)
foreach (i=1:10, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  measSIR %>% pfilter(Np=5000)
} -> pf
logLik(pf) -> ll
logmeanexp(ll,se=TRUE)
```

Comment: We'd love to help you, but we can't possibly help without a [mcve] ... Presumably this is from the `pomp` package ... ???

Comment: yes! I will add an edit with example code.

Comment: Updated it, hope it helps (btw I'm new here so sorry if the way this is posted is still not great >:( )

Comment: This code is fine, but I can't reproduce the problem. When I run this code (on R-devel, pomp version 3.2) I get finite log-likelihoods (-268.7781 for the first `logLik()` call, similar values for the parallelized code). Have you run this from a clean R session? (If the parallelized stuff isn't relevant to your question, you could streamline your question by removing it.)

Comment: Hmm... yes, I have run it without the parallelized code. Hm. So when I run the above code with Beta = 100, it does reproduce the error... this leads me to think that the parameters I am using in my own model are not good enough....

Comment: I guess my main issue is that I don't know what exactly a return value of -Inf signifies. There seems to be no information presented in the documentation of the function

Comment: The `pomp` package in general presupposes a fairly high level of knowledge/sophistication about probability and stochastic model fitting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set `Beta=100` in the code above I can get a negative-infinite log-likelihood.

Replacing the measurement-error snippet with this:

```r
dmeas <- Csnippet("
      double ll = dbinom(reports,H,rho,give_log);
      lik =  (!isfinite(ll) ? -1000 : ll );
")
```

appears to 'solve' the problem, although you should be a little bit careful; papering over numerical cracks like this is sometimes OK, but could conceivably come back to bite you in some way later on. If you just need to avoid non-finite values long enough to get into a reasonable parameter range this might be OK ...

Some guesses as to why this is happening:

- you are somehow getting an "impossible" situation like a positive number of reported cases when the underlying true number of infections is zero.
- Sometimes non-finite log-likelihoods occur when a very small positive probability underflows to zero.  The equivalent here is likely that the probability of infection `1-exp(-Beta*I/N*dt)` goes to 1.0; then any *observed* outcome where less than 100% of the population is infected is impossible.

You can try to diagnose the situation by seeing what the filtered trajectory actually looks like and comparing it with the data, or by adding debugging statements to the code.  If there's a way to run just the deterministic simulation with your parameter values that might tell you pretty quickly what's going wrong.

An easier/more direct way to debug would be to replace the Csnippet you're using for `dmeas` with an R function: this will be slower but easier to work with (especially if you're not familiar with C coding).  If you uncomment the `browser()` statement below, the code will drop into debug mode when you encounter the bad situation ...

```r
dmeas  <- function(reports,H,rho,log, ...) {
    lik <- dbinom(reports,size=H,prob=rho,log=log)
    if (!is.finite(lik)) {
        lik <- -1000
        ## browser()
    }
    return(lik)
}
```

For example:

```
(t = 3, reports = 2, S = 2280, I = 0, R = 35721, H = 0, Beta = 100, 
    mu_IR = 0.5, rho = 0.5, eta = 0.06, N = 38000, log = TRUE)
Browse[1]> debug at /tmp/SO65554258.R!ZlSILG#7: return(lik)
Browse[2]> reports
[1] 2
Browse[2]> H
[1] 0
Browse[2]> rho
[1] 0.5
```

This shows that the problem is indeed that you have a positive number of reported cases when there have been zero infections ... R is trying to compute the binomial probability of observing `reports` cases out when there are `H` infections that are potentially reportable, each reported with a probability `rho`. When the number of trials `N` in a binomial probability `Binom(N,p)` is zero, the only possible outcome is zero 'successes' (reported cases), with probability 1. All other outcomes have probability 0 (and log-probability -Inf).

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed response!! I will be working through it for the next bit. One follow up question I have is: In my csv I'm using, one of the days has a case count of 0. My simulation does not have 0 cases at that day. Is this what you mean by "you are somehow getting an "impossible" situation like a positive number of reported cases when the underlying true number of infections is zero"?

Comment: Could you elaborated what part of the debugging bit of code implicates that there are a positive number of reported cases but 0 infections? I'm assuming there are 2 reports. H is my accumulator variable and it equals 0. So is that what the issue is?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having >0 cases in the simulated process when there are zero cases in the data. The problem is having >0 cases in the data when there are zero *infections* in the simulated process.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am very new to using R so having some extra context is very helpful (I've primarily just followed the online course mentioned above, but it doesn't really give examples of what cases the code could mess up). I really appreciate your responses!!